# Acumatica NoteID in Grid doesn't save

Tags: grid, customization, acumatica

I am adding a notes field to the grid of AP202000 (Vendor Prices) and when I enter something and hit save, it doesn't stick. I have added the `NoteIndicator="True"` to the grid on the AP202000 Page and I have added this code to the APVendorPrice DAC, not as an extension:

```
#region NoteID
    public abstract class noteID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Guid? _NoteID;
    [PXNote]
    public virtual Guid? NoteID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._NoteID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._NoteID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Here is the code for the grid header:

```
<px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Height="144px" Style="z-index: 100" Width="100%" Caption="Sales Prices"
        SkinID="Details" FilterShortCuts="True" NoteIndicator="True" FilesIndicator="True" ActivityIndicator="True" AdjustPageSize="Auto" AllowPaging="True" SyncPosition="true" >
```

I noticed other forums where it said if I would do these two things then the notes field would work, however this is not my case. This is for the note field to be on the grid with each row and would save to each individual row on the grid, not the notes field at the top.

Comment: Can you please add more details. Like to which DAC you have added this code and the ASPX part of the page

Comment: Added to the original post.

Comment: What do you mean by saying **I have added this code to the APVendorPrice DAC, not as an extension**?

Comment: I put this in the Original DAC, because I read somewhere I can't use the PXNote attribute in an extension? Either way, I have also tried this in an extension and this was still giving me the same issue.

Comment: What is the type of your field in the database?

Comment: String and when you add something to the note on the grid, the smart panel comes up and you enter text in, after you close it the note does go to yellow but then it does not allow you to save. And if you change something to save and it refreshes, the note goes away.

Comment: I'm now getting an error saying Arithmetic overflow error converting expression of data type to nvarchar

Comment: Dane, noteId in the Database side should be of type `uniqueidentifier` in case of MS SQL and it's equivalent in case of MySQL. The Note Engine is saving only the reference to your note on the record. The real note is being saved in the separate table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167194/discussion-between-dane-young-and-samvel-petrosov).